# What tool is used for data.stackexchange.com query building

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, technology

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new
Has an awesome tool for creating queries. Is this a third-party tool or was it built in-house?
I'd love to use something similar for SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [data-explorer tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/data-explorer/info) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was built by [Sam Saffron aka waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron) (a former SE developer), as a side project.

It's open source, so you can find the code [here](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/).